# Cannot understand how angle between two vectors is calculated

Tags: linear-algebra, trigonometry, vector-spaces, vectors, normed-spaces

On the picture below I am not getting why we calculate $\cos^{-1}(\frac{1}{3})$ instead of $\cos(\frac{1}{3})$. 
[image]
Sorry if the question is dumb.

Comment: Well, you're looking for the angle which is $\Theta$ in the first equation. Then $\cos\Theta$ is being calculated to have a value of $1/3$. Thus you need to apply the function $\cos^{-1}$ in order to get the argument ($\Theta$) which yields this value. Please keep in mind that $\cos$ is a $2\pi$-periodic function so a check if you got the desired angle is mandatory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have that

$\cos(\theta)=\frac{1}{3}$

However, you are not looking for $\cos(\theta)$, you are looking for $\theta$ itself,

so that is, $\arccos(\frac{1}{3})=\theta$

Answer (score 2):

Notice, in general an inverse trigonometric function gives the value of an angle.

$\cos^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)=1.23\ \text{rad}$ is the angle $(\theta)$ between $v$ & $w$ which you are looking for. While $\cos\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)$ is a value (not an angle )i.e. cosine of angle $\frac 13$ rad.

Answer (score 0):

The angle formed between the two vectors is denoted by θ. Hence, to find the angle, we solve for/find the value for θ.

You ended up with the equation cos θ = <sup>1</sup>⁄<sub>3</sub>.

Finding the value for θ from here is simple. All we have to do is remove the cos function from the left side of the equal sign and we will get the value for θ.

**How we do that:**

1. Take the inverse of cos on both sides.
2. Cancel cos and cos<sup>−1</sup> since, they are opposites. This means that taking cos of a number and taking cos−1 of the result will give you the original value thus, we can ignore the two operations.
3. We are left with θ = cos<sup>−1</sup>(<sup>1</sup>⁄<sub>3</sub>)

**Cos θ = <sup>1</sup>⁄<sub>3</sub>**

**Cos<sup>-1</sup>(Cos θ) = Cos-1(<sup>1</sup>⁄<sub>3</sub>)**

**<strike>Cos-1(Cos</strike> θ) = Cos-1(<sup>1</sup>⁄<sub>3</sub>)**       (Notice θ is the only value on the left side of equal sign)

**θ = Cos<sup>-1</sup>(<sup>1</sup>⁄<sub>3</sub>)**

**θ = 1.23 rad**

*Another way to think of it:*

> Whenever we take something from one side of the equal sign to the other, it becomes the opposite of itself (for + => -, * => /, sin => sin<sup>-1</sup>, etc. and vice versa).

To find θ, we simply take the cos function to the other side therefore, making it cos<sup>-1</sup> resulting in the equation:

**θ = Cos<sup>-1</sup>(<sup>1</sup>⁄<sub>3</sub>)**

Hope that helped.